# Introduce variable within another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the following variable so that I can introduce another variable within it.

the code immediately below is working:

```
$("tbody").on("change", "input", function (ev) 
{
    console.log(this.name, this.value,  ev.target.className);                           
    var checked = $('.capex_opex_1:checked')
    var in_checked =  $('input.capex_opex_1')                               
    if (checked.length > 1) {
    in_checked.not(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');}
});
```

However when I introduce a variable in either **var checked** or **var in_checked** in the code below, I get the error at the bottom

```
var checked = "$('." + ev.target.className + ":checked')"
var in_checked =  "$('input."  +  ev.target.className +  "')"                               
if (checked.length > 1) {
in_checked.not(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');}
```

error:

> RPC:654 Uncaught TypeError: in_checked.not is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement. (RPC:654)
>       at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.js:4737)
>       at HTMLTableSectionElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.2.4.js:4549)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery-2.2.4.js:7807)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (jquery-2.2.4.js:7875)
>       at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.js:365)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-2.2.4.js:137)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery-2.2.4.js:7874)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:5)
>       at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.js:365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't surround it with double quotes otherwise you're effectively converting to a string and the jQuery selector will not work. Open and close the single quotes appropriately.

Try this:

```
var checked = $('.' + ev.target.className + ':checked');
var in_checked = $('input.' + ev.target.className);
```